# Instance of 'Future<bool>, but expect bool

Tags: android, flutter, sqflite

I am new in flutter.And i have a question.I have method checkIsExistByString to check if i have a data before to insert date in sqflite.I expect true or false.

```
class DbManager {

    Future<bool> checkIsExistByString(String title) async {

            await openDb();
            var result = await _database
                .rawQuery('SELECT $Title FROM $tableName WHERE $Title = ?', [title]);

            return Future<bool>.value(result.isEmpty ? true : false);
          }
}
```

When i try to use checkIsExistByString i expect bool, but i have Instance of 'Future

```
void _submit() async {

    print(dbmanager.checkIsExistByString('Title'));//print -- Instance of 'Future<bool>',but i expect true

   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put await.

```
print(await dbmanager.checkIsExistByString('Title'));
```

also there is no need to convert `bool` into `Future<bool>`.

```
 return result.isEmpty ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use await keyword as below :

```
print(await dbmanager.checkIsExistByString('Title'));
```